# How to enable codelens for merging

Tags: visual-studio-code, codelens

I recently got a new device and have been playing around with git and tried to merge two branches, but vscode's codelens doesn't seem to show the usual "accept current change accept incoming change" menu. Instead, it just puts it in raw text - how do I fix this?

What it is currently:
[image]

Desired:
[image]